# Interpolating power series?

Tags: functions, polynomials, power-series

Is there a general algorithm for finding a power series
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$$

with certain properties (i.e. given values of $f(x)$) without knowing $f(x)$ in terms of $x$? (This rules out the possibility of using recursive order derivatives.)

Given a function $y=f(x)$ and the $(x,y)$ values $(1,p), (2,q), (3,r),...$ (without knowing any other values of $f(x)$), we need to find a sequence $a_n$ such that:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n=p$

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n2^n=q$

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n3^n=r$

$...$

Essentially, this would be similar to finding an interpolating polynomial, but rather for an infinite series instead, and the sequence $a_n$ must be non-zero for infinitely $n$.

Edit:

For a single series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n=p$, we can construct a sequence of partial sums

$s_k = \sum_{n=0}^{k} a_n$

such that

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} s_k = p$

The problem, of course is to generalize this for multiple values $f(x)=p,q,r,...$

$s_k(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{k} a_nx^n$

such that

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} s_k(x) = f(x)$

For example, given $x=2$ and a series that converges to $-1$, one solution is to use a geometric series:

$$-2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{4^n} = -2 + \frac{x}{4} + \frac{x^2}{16} + \frac{x^3}{64} + ...$$

However, add in another random point, say $(3,7)$ and the above series doesn't work anymore. In fact, I don't think there is even a geometric series solution for those two points.

---

An approach towards a solution:

So here, we want to solve the example with points $(2,-1)$, and $(3,7)$.

Basically, we need some high degree polynomials whose values are "close enough" to the convergence values. Provided the series above for only $(2,-1)$, I was able to find a degree $8$ polynomial (with rational coefficients) which has a close approximation to the desired convergence values:

$$f(x) = -2 + \frac{x}{4} + \frac{x^2}{16} + \frac{x^4}{4} - \frac{141x^5}{538} + \frac{700x^6}{10018} + \frac{x^7}{636} - \frac{x^8}{1911}$$

$f(2) ≈ -1.097370 ≈ -1$

$f(3) ≈ 6.820336 ≈ 7$

However, as this polynomial is finite degree, it cannot be a power series solution for the given set of points.

---

A more sophisticated approach with a different pair of points $(2,3), (3,7)$:

$$f(x) = 1 + \frac{x}{4} + \frac{x^2}{7} + \frac{x^3}{13} - \frac{x^4}{55} - \frac{x^6}{630} + \frac{x^7}{1679} + \frac{x^8}{1189} - \frac{x^9}{3584}$$

$f(2) ≈ 2.995211 ≈ 3$

$f(3) ≈ 6.989213 ≈ 7$

These approximations are even better!

A search for a closer approximation yields two more terms:

$$f(x) = 1 + \frac{x}{4} + \frac{x^2}{7} + \frac{x^3}{13} - \frac{x^4}{55} - \frac{x^6}{630} + \frac{x^7}{1679} + \frac{x^8}{1189} - \frac{x^9}{3584} + \frac{x^{10}}{115377} - \frac{x^{11}}{351722}$$

$f(2) ≈ 2.998264 ≈ 3$

$f(3) ≈ 6.997349 ≈ 7$

Like the previous example, I had to start out by "guessing" the coefficients so there is really no pattern and thus, cannot be treated as a formal power series with the desired convergence properties.

Comment: I wouldn’t use the word “equivalent” here - it is similar to interpolating polynomials, not equivalent to.

Comment: In particular, we can always interpolate a polynomial, but we can only find a power series which match infinite value pairs $(x_i,y_i)$ under certain circumstances.

Comment: You could find a function that is true for all the (x,y) values, and then find its power series. I don't know if this is what you're asking for, however. Note, not all functions have a power series.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews my question was about finitely many values (pairs) or infinitely many values without any explicit formula... so it's not possible? Edit: I know it is possible for a single value, but two values, three, etc.?

Comment: If $(z_n)$ is a _discrete_ sequence in $\mathbb{C}$ and $\xi_n$ are any complex numbers, then you can always find an analytic function $f$ so that $f(z_n) = \xi_n$. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/136532/655547), for instance. Since you're interested in finitely many points, that's necessarily discrete, and my guess is that (with some work I'm too lazy to do right now) you can extend this to an infinite discrete sequence (and use this extra space to force the coefficients to be nonzero. Say, by making the function get large more quickly than any polynomial).

Comment: Of course it is possible for finitely many values - a polynomial is a power series, and there is a polynomial solution for a power series. If you don’t want to accept a polynomial solution, find a polynomial $p$ for $(x_i,e^{-x_i}y_i)$ and take $f(x)=p(x)e^x.$ The. $f(x_i)=y_i,$ and $f$ is not a polynomial, unless $p=0.$ It isn’t always true for infinitely many points $(x_i,y_i).$ For example, $x_n=\frac1n,y_n=(-1)^n.$

Comment: You also have the problem of examples like $(x_0,y_0)=(2,-1).$ $(x_n,y_n)=\left(\frac1n,\frac n{n-1}\right).$ You get an $f(x)=\frac1{1-x},$ defined for $x\neq 1,$ and only that function. The function works for $x_0,$ but the power series does not.

Comment: For example, if we just have the point $(2, -1)$, we can approximate a series such as $-2 + x/4 + x^2/16 + x^3/64 +...$ which sums to $-1$ given $x=2$. Provided another point, say $(3, 7)$, the above series doesn't work... I like @HallaSurvivor approach to this problem (finding a series satisfying those two points simultaneously)…

Comment: @J.Linne Sure, my point is that there are infinite sets $(x_i,y_i)$ for which there is no power series matching all points. If you add the condition that the $x_i$ have no limit points (I’m not sure the word “discrete” here is a common term for that, but I assume that is what Halla means) then you can solve it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Fair enough. I was also interested in finite number of points too, but more specifically how to solve them (finding the power series solution). I had one approach which I will post to my original question.

Comment: @J.Linne For a finite set of values, any such function is $$p(x)+(x-x_1)(x-x_2)\cdots(x-x_n)h(x)$$ where $h(x)$ is any holomorphic function holomorphic on a ball $B(0,R)$ with some $R>\max |x_i|,$ and $p$ is the  unique polynomial of degree $n$ which  interpolates $(x_1,y_1),\dots,(x_n,y_n).$ You can derive the power series from the power series for $h$ around $0.$